# How to use exec-php(node js) in MVC framework like zend?

Tags: node.js, zend-framework, exec

Basically what I want to do over here is to get data into node server js, data which is returned from a function which is written into a Zend model.

My node js server code is as below:

```
var socket = require( 'socket.io' );
var express = require( 'express' );
var http = require( 'http' );
var execPhp = require('exec-php');

var app = express();
var server = http.createServer( app );

var io = socket.listen( server );

execPhp('../application/modules/front/models/Dbtable/Postcontent.php', 
function(error, php, outprint){
php.fetchEntryAll(function(error, result){
io.sockets.emit('showfeeds', result);
});
});

server.listen( 7000 );
```

so when I tried to execute above code it gives me error like below:

Error: Command failed: PHP Fatal error: Class 'Zend_Db_Table_Abstract' not found in /Data/www/XXX/application/modules/front/models/Dbtable/Postcontent.php on line 3

same code works when I use core PHP instead of Zend.

So I believe that we can't use OOP stuff with exec-php.

Is there any solution here?

Reference link to exec-php:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/exec-php

Answer (score 0):

The problem you ran into is not about OOP but autoloading your object class file(s).

While you have a path defined to your first file some or all of the following files don't have a path defined for their dependencies--like an Abstract class.

ZF1 files should actually have require statements and work without an auto loader. What you are missing and need is the same in your own modules files.

In your `application/modules/front/models/Dbtable/Postcontent.php` file you have to *hint* the path to the Abstract class as a `require_once` statement.